# Can't remove some of the numbers from the list (from, to), only removes first number

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

```
array1 = []

while True:
    try:
        number = input("number('end' to continue): ")
        if number == "end":
            break
        number = int(number)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    else:
        array1.append(number)

if len(array1) == 0:
    print("There is no elements in the array!")
    exit()
else:
    array1.sort()
    print("Your array:", array1)

while True:
    try:
        numberFrom = int(input("Remove elements 'from': "))
    except ValueError:
        continue
    else:
        if numberFrom in array1:
            break
        else:
            continue

while True:
    try:
        numberTo = int(input("Remove elements 'to': "))
    except ValueError:
        continue
    else:
        if numberTo in array1:
            if numberTo >= numberFrom:
                break
        else:
            continue

for i in array1:
    if i in range(numberFrom, numberTo):
        array1.remove(i)

print(array1)
```

For exaple:

entered 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
got [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
enter 1
enter 3
got [2, 3, 4, 5]

Need to get [4, 5] (because from 1 to 3 is 1, 2, 3)

Please help idk what to do :c

For those who interested, text from the original exercise that i tried to complete:

"Given a one-dimensional array of numeric values, numbering N elements. Exclude from the array elements belonging to the interval [B;C]." (GoogleTranslate)

Comment: Don't modify a list while you are iterating over it, use a copy instead. Here you can simply replace `for i in array1:` by `for i in array1[:]:`

Comment: Keep in mind that a `range` does **not** contain its end value.

Comment: What exactly are the constraints on the input and the expected logic? Do you have all numbers from 1 to N and want to remove those between B and C? Are they originally sorted? Whatever the logic is, your approach is not a good one in python.

Comment: Given a List named `my_list` you can most simply exclude elements in interval `b to c` using a List comprehension: `new_list = [x for x in my_list if x not in range(b, c+1)]` . This assumes `c` is inclusive hence using `c+1`. Note the task as you describe does not demand the List and Values are input by keyboard.

Comment: @user19077881 `if x>=b and x<c` should be marginally faster than `if x not in range(b, c+1)`

Comment: If the list contains all sorted values from 1 to N, then a simple `lst[b-1:c] = []` also works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fixed code

i modified the last 3 lines to actually get an index and then return the rest of the array by concatenating them

```py
array1 = []

while True:
    try:
        number = input("number('end' to continue): ")
        if number == "end":
            break
        number = int(number)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    else:
        array1.append(number)

if len(array1) == 0:
    print("There is no elements in the array!")
    exit()
else:
    array1.sort()
    print("Your array:", array1)

while True:
    try:
        numberFrom = int(input("Remove elements 'from': "))
    except ValueError:
        continue
    else:
        if numberFrom in array1:
            break
        else:
            continue

while True:
    try:
        numberTo = int(input("Remove elements 'to': "))
    except ValueError:
        continue
    else:
        if numberTo in array1:
            if numberTo >= numberFrom:
                break
        else:
            continue

# Here is what I have added
index1 = array1.index(numberFrom)
index2 = array1.index(numberTo)
array1 = array1[:index1] + array1[index2 + 1:]

print(array1)
```